# Jetpack Navigation with WebView is not working properly

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-webview, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I have a `Fragment` with `ViewPager` inside it, which contains 3 tabs. I have used **Jetpack navigation** to handle navigation. In the first tab I have a `Fragment` with `WebView`, as per native behaviour of Jetpack navigation, it recreates view every time we navigate to another fragment.

Here is the problem, it loads the URL every time when I navigate back to the `WebView` `Fragment`. That can't be handled using live data.

I have tried to cache `Webview` content, but it is just makes loading faster but it's not immediate.

here is my code snippet

> MyFragment.kt

```
class MyFragment : BaseViewModelFragment<MyViewModel>(), View.OnClickListener {
    override fun getContentResource(): Int = R.layout.fragment_my
    override fun buildViewModel(): MyViewModel {
        return ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)[MyViewModel::class.java]
    }

    override fun initLiveDataObservers() {
        super.initLiveDataObservers()
    }

    override fun initViews() {
        super.initViews()
        setupWebView()
    }

    private fun setupWebView() = with(webView) {
        settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        settings.setAppCachePath("/data/data/" + activity?.packageName + "/cache")
        settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true)
        settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK
        webViewClient = MyWebviewClient()
        webChromeClient = MyChromeClient()
        loadUrl("http://google.com")
    }
}
```

Any help would be appriated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by adding `WebView` run time

```
class MyFragment : BaseViewModelFragment<MyViewModel>(), View.OnClickListener {

    private val myWebview by lazy {
        WebView(requireContext().applicationContext).apply {
            webViewClient = MyWebviewClient()
            webChromeClient = MyChromeClient()
        }
    }

    override fun getContentResource(): Int = R.layout.fragment_home

    override fun buildViewModel(): MyViewModel {
        return ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)[MyViewModel::class.java]
    }

    override fun initLiveDataObservers() {
        super.initLiveDataObservers()
    }

    override fun initViews() {
        super.initViews()
        container.addView(myWebview, ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
        )
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        (myWebview.parent as ViewGroup).removeView(myWebview)
        super.onDestroyView()
    }
}
```